# Load external HTTPS script in HTTP WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, security, ssl, https

I am trying to load a script on a WordPress HTTP site using PHP. The script itself is on another site, and is only accessible through HTTPS. I am loading the script using the line:

```
wp_enqueue_script('airtable_embed', 'https://static.airtable.com/js/embed/airtable_embed.js');
```

However, when the page loads, the https in the url is always replaced by http, and the script is *not* available through HTTP - only HTTPS. Since it can't find the HTTP version, it gives the following error:

```
http://static.airtable.com/js/embed/airtable_embed.js?ver=4.3.1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

The WordPress documentation says that

> Remote scripts can be specified with a protocol-agnostic URL, e.g. //otherdomain.com/js/their-script.js.

So, I think the reason the protocol is being changed from HTTPS to HTTP is that WordPress forces it to use the same protocol as the current site. How can I get around this and include the HTTPS script in my HTTP site?

Comment: There's a reason they don't want you include HTTPS scripts on a HTTP site. There are a lot of things you can't do on HTTP, that you can do on HTTPS since HTTP isn't secured.

Comment: Just a small point, you didnt use a _protocol-agnostic URL_ You quoted `https:` thats protocol specific

Answer (score 0):

If you paste the airtable embed snippet into an HTML page and then inspect the DOM, you can just grab the raw HTML for your wordpress site.